# Tool for Harmonic Analysis & Synthesis

Tags: frequency-spectrum, music, peak-detection, sound

I've been using a program for identifying harmonics for a wave after doing a fourier analysis.

http://www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/resource/sfs/esynth.htm

I would like to be able to tweak some of the harmonics involed in a wave and also to add harmonics.

The program mentioned above permits this kind of operations but it isn't precise.

Does anyone know of a good tool for harmonic analysis and synthesis like the one mentioned above?

ps:It's important that the program exports the harmonics to a file.

thanks.

Comment: it doesn't sound like you're writing your own algorithm, but if you want to go that way, you need a good pitch detector to know the period (to a precision of a fraction of a sample) and a good resampling or interpolation algorithm (like the polyphase thingie).  from that you can resample every period so that each cycle has something like, say, 256 points.  from that you can DFT and you will have the magnitude and phase information for the fundamental and 126 more harmonics.  i've written about how to do this regarding [Wavetable Synthesis](http://musicdsp.org/files/Wavetable-101.pdf).

Comment: oh, i just realized how old this question is.

Comment: Requests for existing software tools are off-topic, as the answers usually won't require any signal processing content. In addition, they fall into the "help me shop" category, which is largely deprecated on SE sites (cf. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/).

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson Nice article, btw.

Comment: thnx, @datageist.  it needs to be updated (with nicer drawings), but so does the Audio EQ Cookbook.

Answer (score -2):

Try NCH Software

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NCH_Software):

> NCH Software is a software development company founded in 1993 in
>   Canberra, Australia. The Colorado office was started in April 2008 due
>   to the large U.S. customer base. NCH Software primarily sells to
>   individuals via their website.

And further

> Browser Toolbar
>
> During the installation process NCH Software also by default (but you
>   can uncheck the option during install) installs Google Chrome. This
>   can be unselected during install or removed after install. In older
>   versions of their software a browser toolbar powered by Conduit,[11]
>   was installed as well as making changes to the default homepage and
>   search engine.

Comment: So which product of NCH can do harmonic analysis?